# how to print to console graphically in C on unix

Tags: c, unix, printing

So I'm familiar with printf and the like, but I need to update a single line on the screen without having multiple lines scrolling. I have found libraries to do this in windows (conio.h) but not in unix. I need to be able to run this in cygwin, but any unix examples would be welcome.

I found the following [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149784/linux-unix-console-graphics-control) , but I don't think it quite closes the question for my needs.

Thanks for your help

Comment: There isn't going to be one single cross platform way to do this. In unix, the idea is that you move the cursor to a specific place on the screen. You can do it with escape characters, but it's not trivial.

Comment: You might be looking for ncurses?

Comment: Why was not that SO answer useful to you? It describes exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you're trying to do a text-mode full-screen application (in which case ncurses is probably what you want) or just want to update a single line in-place (e.g., you want to update an "X percent done" indicator from 1 to 100, with all the output appearing on the same line so when X percent done is printed, it prints "over" the previous X-1 percent done indicator). In the latter case, you can write code that's relatively portable, and considerably simpler as well. For example, something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>    // Used only for "Sleep" in our simulated work load
#include <stdio.h>

void do_work() {
    // Simulated work load. Just waste some time:
    Sleep(100);
}

int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        char buffer[82];
        sprintf(buffer, "%d percent done", i+1);
        printf("\r%-79s", buffer);
        do_work();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an intermediate buffer and not sending the output directly with one `printf`??

Comment: So it'll always print out as the same total length (an entire line), regardless of the length of the number.

Comment: I usually also go the step using an intermediate buffer, but in this case this could have been done using without it, yet keeping the length. The idea is, to keep the strings in place, so they won't jump around. printf("\r% 4d%% done", i+1); fflush(stdout); does the trick just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want Ncurses for this. It's a library which allows you to edit any character on the screen.